# Issue with showing date when csv file opened in MS Excel 2010

Tags: excel, date, csv

I have a problem with exporting to CSV format. This issue is reproduced on Excel 2010 and isn't on Excel 2013,2016. Column which contains date format value is automatically converted from `MM-DD-yyyy hh:mm a` to `MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM` (24hours format). When I open *.csv file using notepad everything works fine.

Maybe it depends on custom user preferences in Excel? Could you provide solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: The question is off-topic. It is not a programming question, it is about using MS Excel

Comment: Notepad does no conversion, so it displays exactly what is stored in the file as text. Notepad doesn't do math, allow formulas, run macros, conditional formatting or anything else either. What Notepad does is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I only was trying to get confirmation of my assumptions.

Comment: Usually has something to do with Windows Regional short date settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening text files such as CSV in Excel, Excel uses the most recently used settings for the `Text To Columns` feature (which are the same settings used for the import text file feature).

Furthermore, if you don't specify ***all*** of the Text To Columns settings, Excel will use the most recently used values, or the defaults.

Excel's re-use of the previous settings will explain why you are seeing different results on different versions of Excel - It's not because the versions differ, it's because each installation has a different set of most recently used preferences for Text To Columns.

You can step through the Text To Columns wizard (on the Data tab in the Data Tools group), chooisng ***all*** of the preferences you'd like, and then try opening the CSV file again.